# MOSS 2007 Create Lookup Column but list is not in dropdown

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have create a list in sharepoitn and I am trying to add a column whih is a look up to another list. The list that I am trying to look up is a parent site to the site I a currentley on. I do not see the list that I wish to add in the drop down. Any ideas why this list is not apearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup column dropdown will only find lists at the current site level.  What you want to do is the following:

1. Create a site column on the parent site (the site that has the source list).  This site column should be a lookup to the source list & column that you need.
2. On the child site's list, add a column, and point to the site column you just created in step 1. This should give you the functionality you're looking for.