# Sharepoint Lookup

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

I have been absolutely stymied by Sharepoint lookups and the complete lack of information anywhere that relates to my problem so one last stab at seeing if anyone has a clue if not I am going to find another job which doesnt involve the use of this very good but highly complicated system.

My problem is that I want to add a column in list 1 that looks up a column in list 2, all very easy you may think and the nice videos on you tube make it seem very easy. So imagine the frustration when I create the column choose the appropriate list from "get information from" drop down and then go to the "in this column" drop down to find the fields i want are missing. I have tried this many ways and could not resolve it. So I decided to start again and set up a brand new list 2 which contains just 4 columns each created manually one column is "just single line of text" called Financial year the other three are a "number" and called Population, Dwellings and Non Domestic. Now having done that I would expect to see thos 4 columns (Financial year, Population, Dwellings and Non Domestic) all appear in the "in this column" drop down when setting up the lookup. But no of course not bloody Sharepoint will only show: Title, Financial year, ID , Content Type, version, and Title (linked to item) none of which I am the slightest bit interested in. I want to look up  Population, or Dwellings or Non Domestic. Why is this so easy to do in Excel but in Sharepoint it seems as if Bill Gates has decided he's in charge of what people lookup!! in a word its crap.

I should have added that the same happens whatever list I select to look up from.

Comment: How are you trying to create the lookup list? Visual Studio? Sharepoint Designer? Also which version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2007 and creating the lookup list by going to specific list in Sharepoint and the add column etc

Comment: Check the anwsers in this forum, maybe one of them helps you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/09e22dc0-817a-4411-9db4-44661e148644/lookup-column-in-sharepoint-2007?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: also check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118315/moss-2007-create-lookup-column-but-list-is-not-in-dropdown

Comment: Thank you the first one does work but what a laborious process and how mad is that, that I have to create an additional column in list 2 which is basically an = value in another column. No wonder windows is full of rubbish code when their developers come up with bizarre logic like this. As I said before crap but thanks for finding me a work round however laborious.

Comment: Well blaming developers for the choices they took (especially for such complex systems) mostly is because due to lack of understanding how stuff works. If you think you know more and can find a better solution than a big team of high qualified software developers at Microsoft did, go ahead show us your wisdom. Unless you can't just stop talking bad about stuff you don't understand and accept the fact that it just is the way it is.

Comment: Yes I appreciate that I dont know what I dont know and there is no way I would try and claim I know better however things like this are so frustrating and users never get to know why. And you have to admit that the solution is not exactly a demonstration of an intuitive product which is unusual for MS.